# How to optimize nested looping or the method that is executed in every iteration?

Tags: c#, nested, data-mining

I understand that the title of this question doesn't say much about the problem I'm struggling with.
I have a text file filled with purchase orders from a online bookstore. This text file is about 900,000 lines long and each line contains two fields separated by comma (customer_id,book_id). I wanted to do some datamining and thought it would be fun to find out some statistics about books so I created two methods. GetOrderCount(string x, string y) and AllPairs(). First one calculates how many customers bought two specific books together and the second one calculates all possible pairs (all size 2 combinations). However this takes very long time to run. Looking at the code is there something specific that could take a long time? And is the nested loop in AllPairs() complex enough that it would justify using parallel For? Also I picked some of the structures so that it would make better sense but they might not be meant for these kind of operations. Any pointers towards why this code is so slow would be perfection.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookStats
{
class Order
{
    Dictionary<int, HashSet<String>> orders;
    List<string> books;

    public Order(String path)
    {
        orders = GetOrders(path, out books);
    }

    private Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> GetOrders(string path, out List<string> distinctBooks)
    {
        Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>> items = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>();
        distinctBooks = new List<string>();
        List<string> allBooks = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string s = String.Empty;
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] line = s.Split(',');
                try
                {
                    int id = int.Parse(line[0]);
                    allBooks.Add(line[1]);
                    if (items.ContainsKey(id))
                    {
                        items[id].Add(line[1]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HashSet<string> customerBooks = new HashSet<string>();
                        customerBooks.Add(line[1]);
                        items.Add(id, customerBooks);
                    }
                }
                catch{ }
            }
        }
        distinctBooks.AddRange(allBooks.Distinct());
        return items;
    }

    public int GetOrderCount(string x, string y){
        int count = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int,HashSet<string>> order in orders)
        {
            var receipt = order.Value;
            if (receipt.Contains(x) && receipt.Contains(y))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void GetAllPairs()
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < books.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < books.Count;j++)
            {
                int count = GetOrderCount(books[i], books[j]);
                Console.WriteLine(j);

            }
            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
        }
    }

    public int GetBookCount() {
        return books.Count;
    }

    public void GetCustomerPurchase(int id)
    {
        foreach (string s in orders[id])
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Raamat " + s);
        }
    }



}
```

}

EDITED: Edited the code to match suggestions given by @Chris and @Anony-Mousse

Comment: Give it a try at see what happens! Two small things: in the for loop with `j`, start on `i + 1` and remove the `if`. In `GetOrderCount`, iterate on the dictionary directly (giving you a `KeyValuePair<>`). Right now you're doing two lookups per iteration when you wouldn't have too. Also, this would look very neat using LINQ.

Comment: Use a *PROFILER*. Thats what they are for.

Comment: Although LINQ looks neat I've read it is bigger performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops are actually four levels deep (third loop is in “GetOrdersCount” and the fourth is “Contains”). Thats probably what makes it slow. *Use a profiler to see where you need to optimize*.

For a starter, replace

```
Dictionary<int, List<String>> orders;
```

with

```
Dictionary<int, Set<String>> orders;
```

And do the necessary changes to the code.

Build optimized data structures such as inverted sorted lists to accelerate the costly operations. A set is faster than a list for “Contains” for example, too.

Comment: Used a profiler and it states that Contains() is the most resource heavy process in there even after I replaced List<string> with HashSet<String>. Looks like there's nothing else to optimize :D

Comment: So then you'll need to look into inverted indexes.

Comment: I automatically thought that while customer_id being first in the data structure it would be smart to use customer as Key value in the dictionary. However I couldn't have been more wrong. Now it seems logical that since most of the searches are based on book_id-s it would be sensible to use book ID as the key and then put customers in a HashSet that matches this key. Also I now converted both values into int because it seems like Contains() methods run faster on int values. Thanks a lot for this inverted index idea.

Comment: The time it takes to run a Contains() method isn't that much longer but since I have to run it multiple times it really adds up in total performance.

Comment: Consider building the all-pairs the other way around. Make a matrix for them, and then process every set only once, incrementing similarity counters. That is what column-wise similarity processing does.